# How to do Mongodb aggregation arithmetic operator in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Mongodb Aggregation Framework, you have arithmetic operators like $multiply or $add and so on, I know you can do something similar to `{ $multiply : [ myField, 0 ] }` easily in MongoDb, but how can you do it in Java? I tried `new BasicDBObject("$multiply", new BasicDBObject(myField, 0))"` in Java, but I got

```
"errmsg" : "exception: the $multiply operator does not accept an object as an operand".
```

So I wonder if you can do the same thing in Java?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value of `$multiply` operator should be an array not an object. So, in Java the code will be:

```
BasicDBList args  = new BasicDBList();
args.add(myField);
args.add(0);

new BasicDBObject("$multiply", args)
```